# I was having an Internal server error 500 on sending a SOAP request

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, soap

I am getting this error "POST :
http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl 
500 (Internal Server Error)" on attempting to send a SOAP request using Java script and HTML5. I'm seeing this error in the console of chrome.I already installed CORS plugin(to remove the Allow-control-Allow-origin error) and added lines of code to remove the CORS problem.

This WSDL is working fine in soap UI and giving correct response.

[screenshot of the error,click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNshu.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <script >
        function soapReq()
  {
  
  console.log("Hi");
  var str = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-  envelope" xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">' 
   '<soap:Header>' +
     ' <httpProtocol> ' +
        '<customHeaders>' +
          '<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="True" />' +
          '<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />' +
          '<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />' +
          ' </customHeaders>' +
      '</httpProtocol>' + 
 '</soap:Header>' +
   '<soap:Body>' +
      '<blz:getBank>' +
         '<blz:blz>66452776</blz:blz>' +
      '</blz:getBank>' +
    
   '</soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Envelope>' ;

        function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  
  
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
 
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
   
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>');
}

// Make the actual CORS request.

  var url = 'http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
 console.log(text);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  xhr.send(str);

}


 
           
    </script>
</head>
<body>

 <form>
    <input type="button" value="SOAP Request" onclick="soapReq();" />
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
 <form>
    <input type="button" value="SOAP Request" onclick="soapReq();" />
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the problem is with the server side - which you've shown zero code for

Comment: That is a server error, you will have to debug it there, with the information you gave it is impossible to help.

Comment: The request will return the response from the server which is in your case a 500 error. This will be handled in the browser console. But the actual error is on your server side. If you have access to server console, check the log. or else, inform the admin with the parameters or your request details.

Comment: Issus is on server side. But, you are saying that similar request sent from SOAP UI fetches successfully. Are you setting correct request headers ?

Comment: ok,actually this is a web service which i found online so i have no idea about the server console. Any working ones u guys know of?

Comment: yes , similar request in soap UI gives correct response

Comment: i have the same problem, did you solve it ?